# How can I extend FullCalendarDayGrid to allow `eventResize` where `allDay===false`

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) I want to be able to resize calendar events from the month view that have a `allDay` value of `false`. In versions of FullCalendar that used jQuery we were able to extend the relevant function like so.

```
$.extend(true, $.fullCalendar.DayGrid.prototype, {
    fgSegHtml(seg, disableResizing) {
        // do all the stuff that fgSegHtml usually does but change some conditionals to no longer care about allDay
    },
});
```

I'm trying to accomplish something similar in V4 of FullCalendar. My problem is that I can't access the relevant function. I can find it in FullCalendar's [souce](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/daygrid/SimpleDayGridEventRenderer.ts#L23) but I can't find it from my console or in a executed `js` file.

I thought the function to extend would be at `FullCalendarDayGrid.SimpleDayGrid.prototype.render()` but that is not the case.

Does anyone know how I can extend the function [`SimpleDayGridEventRenderer.renderSegHtml()`](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/daygrid/SimpleDayGridEventRenderer.ts#L16)?

Comment: "resize calendar events that have a allDay value of false"...this was possible simply by setting https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventDurationEditable to true. No need to modify source code. The same can be set in v4 - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDurationEditable. As the doc says, in v4 you also have to enable the "interaction" plugin. So I can't understand why you'd need to modify the source code to allow events to be resized - unless I'm misunderstanding the scenario?

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the comment. Looking at those docs that does seem like it should do what I want but when I try setting it to true nothing changes. Looking at the [line of code](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/daygrid/SimpleDayGridEventRenderer.ts#L23) that controls this in FC it appears the conditional would fail as soon as it resolved allDay to false. Have you had success resizing non-allDay events with eventDurationEditable set to true?

Comment: You don't need to ask me, just try out the demo on the [fullCalendar home page](https://fullcalendar.io/). Switch to the "week" or "day" view and try resizing any of the events outside the all-day section. Here is the codepen for that demo, which shows you how it's set up, and has a link to the event data: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001 N.B. in case you're wondering, it sets `editable:true` rather than `eventDurationEditable` but as per the docs, making `editable` true enables editing including durations and dragging, so it comes to the same thing.

Comment: Note that this only allows resizing from the _end_ of the event. Normally to resize from the start, you'd have to drag it to change the start time, and then resize to change the end. But in v4 if you want to allow resizing from the start of the event, there is a [new option](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventResizableFromStart) available to allow that, although from what I can see it only seems to apply to all-day events.

Comment: P.S. Clearly, if you are in a non-time-aware view such as "month", then it's impossible to resize a non-all-day event, because it requires an end time, not just a date, and when dragging it around on a view with no times listed, it's impossible for the calendar to know what time you wanted it to end. It occurs to me now that maybe that's the scenario you're describing? Having read your question again, you did mention the dayGrid view specifically, and of course that view doesn't have times defined on it. To get what you want you'd be better to use the "agenda" view instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wanting to resize a non-allDay event on the 'month' view. In the past when a user resizes an event on the month view only the start date or end date would change. The hour and minute values are unaffected. I can imagine cases where this would be undesired but it works for us. I managed to find the function in my console but it's in a closure and as such cannot be extended. So I may be at a loss here. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now is that you could conceivably create your own custom view which is basically identical to the dayGrid in every respect (i.e. you copy it!) except that you change this particular method to do what you want in respect of resizing. And then you use that custom view in your calendars instead of the standard one.

Comment: Either that or you submit a patch to fullCalendar for integration into the product which perhaps provides an user-settable option to allow resizing in the daygrid, and you also provide modified source code which will allow the behaviour if the option is set true. That way it's a configurable option for those who want it. Obviously there's no guarantee the maintainers would accept it, so you might want to discuss it with them first. But that's another option I guess.